# How to select all the elements before last p element via XPath?

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, scrapy

```
<div id="something">
    <a id="dd_start">
    <p>A</p
    <h2>B</h2>
    <p>C</p>
    <h5>D</h5>
    <script> </script>
    <p>E</p>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

How to get all the elements before the last `p`?  I want `p`, `h2`, `p`, and `h5`: A B C D.

I tried:

```
item['contents'] = ' '.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="something"]/preceding-sibling::*p//text()').extract()).strip()

item['contents'] = ' '.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="something"]/preceding-sibling::p[last()]//text()').extract()).strip()

item['contents'] = ' '.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="something"]/p[last()]/preceding-sibling::*//text()').extract()).strip()
```

can't seem to work.   My content always return empty.

Comment: Did you intend for the text you added to be ***within*** or ***between*** `p`, `h2`, etc elements?  You're showing it *between* right now.

Comment: hmm i want all the texts before the last <p> .. my client's website soemtimes mixes with other like h2 or h3.. i actually wanna scrape the contents out..

Comment: I could [go on and on with updates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37242011/290085), guessing what you want, or you could save yourself and your readers lot of time and create a **[mcve]** *as you really should have done in the first place.*

Answer (score 2):

For this HTML,

```
<div id="something">
    <p/>
    <h2/>
    <p/>
    <h5/>
    <script/>
    <p/>
    <div/>
</div>
```

To select all siblings elements preceding the last `p` element under the `div` with `id="something"`, use this XPath:

```
//div[@id="something"]/p[last()]/preceding-sibling::*
```

to return

```
<p/>
<h2/>
<p/>
<h5/>
<script/>
```

as requested.

---

**Update 1**: For this updated HTML,

```
<div id="something">
    <p/>A
    <h2/>B
    <p/>C
    <h5/>D
    <script/>
    <p/>E
    <div/>
</div>
```

this XPath

```
//div[@id="something"]/p[last()]/preceding-sibling::text()
```

will now select

```
A
B
C
D
```

as requested in your latest update.

---

**Update 2**: If your HTML is more like this,

```
<div id="something">
    <p>A</p>
    <h2>B</h2>
    <p>C</p>
    <h5>D</h5>
    <script/>
    <p>E</p>
    <div/>
</div>
```

this XPath

```
//div[@id="something"]/p[last()]/preceding-sibling::*/text()
```

will now select the text nodes within the preceding sibling elements:

```
A
B
C
D
```

---

Comment: no need to add /text()? but i tried without text() just now still can't :(

Comment: You said that you wanted `p`, `h2`, `p`, and `h5`, and your example didn't show any text.   Yes, you can get text, but you'll have to be more specific: Edit your question, add text to your example, and state which text should and which text should not be returned.

Comment: yaya but it still returns empty :(

Comment: Your HTML example wasn't well-formed, which it must be in order to use XPath.  I've closed the tags for you, so it's well formed.   Given well-formed XML, the XPath I've shown returns the elements requested.

Answer (score 0):

```
//p[last()]/preceding-sibling::*
```

- Use `last()` to point the last `<p>`.
- Then use `*` to select all preceding siblings of `<p>`